# Is there a better way to return the same string literal from both a static and non-static function?

Tags: c++, templates

My c++ is pretty rusty and generics always confuse me anyway, so the combination is not good for my brain,  so here is my problem.

I have a set of classes that are all going to look like this:

```
class MyEvent2 : public Event 
{

    public:
    static constexpr char* CLASS_NAME = "MyEvent2";
    MyEvent2(Object& sender) :  Event(sender)
    {
    }

    virtual ~MyEvent2() {}

    static const char* EventId() {
        return MyEvent2::CLASS_NAME;
    }

    const char* eventId() override {
        return MyEvent2::CLASS_NAME;
    }
};
```

The classes will be used to register event handlers on an event bus, so I add the handlers like so.

```
  EventBus::AddHandler<MyEvent>(*this);  
  EventBus::AddHandler<MyEvent2>(*this);
```

then I create intances of the events and fire them like this:

```
MyEvent e1(*this);
MyEvent2 e2(*this);
EventBus::FireEvent(e1);
EventBus::FireEvent(e2);
```

My question is how do I make this generic?  I would like to be able to make some derived "Event" class where I just need to include the one line that really needs to be unique

```
static constexpr char* CLASS_NAME = "TheClassName";
```

btw: I know could use typeid to get something like this, but I can't use it on Arduino devices.

and then add unique "Event" specific fields and members.

Here is what I have done so far:

I created a template class (or should it be called a class template?):

```
template<class T>
class ArduinoEvent : public Event 
{

    public:
    T(Object& sender) :  Event(sender)
    {
    }

    virtual ~T() {}

    static const char* EventId() {
        return T::CLASS_NAME;
    }

    const char* eventId() override {
        return T::CLASS_NAME;
    }
};
```

But I am not sure how to use this or if this is even the right direction.

Comment: @Ron, why would that be? The two are orthogonal concepts: `static` specifies the lifetime while `constexpr` specifies that the expression result will be available at compile-time.

Comment: The constructor and destructor for your template class are not named right. Use the template name for constructor name: `ArduinoEvent(...) : ... {}`.

Comment: Note that you couldn't use `typeid` anyway, because the runtime type names it produces aren't guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: You should declare string literals as `char[]`, not `char *`. Saves a pointer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try with [Curiosly Recurring Pattern (CRTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).
It would look something like following  :

```
template <typename  T>
class BaseEvent : public Event {
    public:
        static constexpr const char* id = T::CLASS_NAME;

        constexpr const char* eventId() const {
            return T::CLASS_NAME;
        }
};
```

The template would then be used to instantiate new event classes as follows:

```
class MyEvent1 : public BaseEvent<MyEvent1> {
    public:
        static constexpr const char* CLASS_NAME = "MyEvent1";
};

class MyEvent2 : public BaseEvent<MyEvent2> {
    public:
        static constexpr const char* CLASS_NAME = "MyEvent2";
};
```

You could then use these classes as expected:

```
int main() {

    MyEvent1 e1;
    cout << e1.eventId() 
         << ", " 
         << MyEvent1::id
         << endl;

    MyEvent2 e2;
    cout << e2.eventId() 
         << ", "
         << MyEvent2::id
         << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You can check that `eventId()` behaves as expected in [this online example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rpbebXJTXxlpdkX0)). Note that the template `BaseEvent` needs to inherit from `Event`  if you want to handle all events in a polymorphic way.

Comment: Note that you also can keep the dot syntax and make `eventId` static. Would you mind mentioning it in your answer? Thanks.

Comment: `BaseEvent` needs to inherit from `Event`.

Comment: @Guillaume: thanks. I've provided also a static variant in the example.

Comment: @StPiere Thanks, I think this might work for me,  let me try it out

Comment: This seems to work nicely,  I may post my final classes as an edit or answer since this was a really nice direction, but did not have all the details - thanks again

Comment: I've made an edit to add Event as base class as recommended by @Yacc and to explain why it is needed.  I've also added a link to the CRTP definition on wikipedia.